# Customize PrimeNg <p-dataTable> column names

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

My HTML page has 2 tables and both of them has different column names. My first table has column as `Application ID` and `Application Type` where as my second table has columns `File Name` and `Checkbox s`(to select and delete file). For this scenario I have to use PrimeNg data table i.e. `<p-dataTable>`. Can I customize the data table column names? Please guide me how to achieve this?

So far what i did is:

table.ts as below

```
folderData = FolderData[];
```

(model) FolderData.ts as below

```
appID: string;
appType: string;
filename: string;
checkBox: boolean;
```

table.html as below

```
**First Data Table**
<p-dataTable [value]="folderData ">
  <p-header [style]="{'width': '100%'}">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
      Big Table
    </div>
  </p-header>

  <p-column field="Col1" header="Application ID" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}"></p-column>
  <p-column field="Col2" header="Application Name" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>

**Second Data Table**
<p-dataTable [value]="folderData ">
  <p-header [style]="{'width': '100%'}">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
      Big Table
    </div>
  </p-header>

  <p-column field="Col1" header="File Name" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}"></p-column>
  <p-column field="Col2" header="" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}"><input type="checkbox"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I am not able to figure out how to customize the column names so I have har codded them. Please guide.

Comment: can you create a stsckblitz for this??

Comment: Use dynamic columns.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML side, you have to bind the name of the property of your object in 'field'.

Instead of :

```
<p-column field="Col1" header="Application ID" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}"></p-column>
```

Try:

```
<p-column field="appID" header="Application ID" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '200px'}"></p-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with yours, and I ımplemented like below

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="datasource" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedRow"
                                     dataKey="grpCode"
                                     [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
                                     (onLazyLoad)="loadMainGroupsLazy($event)"
                                     [rows]="perPageRecord" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3"
                                     [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]">
                            <p-column field="grpCode">
                                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                    Plan Kodu
                                    <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="sort(2)">
                            <span
                                [ngClass]="getDirection(2)"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-column>
                            <p-column field="isMandatory">
                                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                    Zorunlu mu?
                                    <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="sort(3)">
                                        <span [ngClass]="getDirection(3)"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template let-col let-plan="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                                    <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="plan[col.field]" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-column>
                            <p-column field="validityStartDate">
                                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                    Başlangıç Tarihi
                                    <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="sort(3)">
                                        <span [ngClass]="getDirection(3)"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template let-col let-plan="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                                    <span>{{plan[col.field] | date: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}}</span>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-column>
                            <p-column field="validityEndDate">
                                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                    Bitiş Tarihi
                                    <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="sort(3)">
                                        <span [ngClass]="getDirection(3)"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template let-col let-plan="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                                    <span>{{plan[col.field] | date: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}}</span>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-column>

                        </p-dataTable>
```